# tikz externalise as svg instead of pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, svg

i'm using the `\tikzexternalize` command to export all my tikz pictures out of my big (main-)document.

For some reasons i need these pictures in `svg`-format. 
Is there a way to externalize the files into a svg instead of pdf?

I tried to convert the pdf to svg using inkscape but inkscape doesn't know the latex-font i used.

I know that i can use `standalone` and then `dvisvgm --no-fonts`. I'd would like to avoid this solution cause i have many tikzpictures. This solution would mean copy and paste for every single tikz picture.

As always thanks in advance

Comment: Did you already have a look at [`svg-inkscape`](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg-inkscape) or [`svg`](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg)?

Comment: @timothymctim i didn't read the whole documentations, but aren't these packages for including svg in my document?
i created many `tikz pictures` and `pgf plots` that are included in my document using the tikz code. i need these pictures as separate pictures in svg-format.